# DFS Medium Question: Find the string in grid, What's wrong in my code?

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I am stuck in a Geekforgeeks question(https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-the-string-in-grid0111/1)

Descriptions are here: Find the string in grid

Given a 2D grid of n*m of characters and a word, find all occurrences of given word in grid. A word can be matched in all 8 directions at any point. Word is said to be found in a direction if all characters match in this direction (not in zig-zag form). The 8 directions are, horizontally left, horizontally right, vertically up, vertically down, and 4 diagonal directions.

Note: The returning list should be lexicographically smallest. If the word can be found in multiple directions starting from the same coordinates, the list should contain the coordinates only once.

Example 1:

Input:
grid = {{a,b,c},{d,r,f},{g,h,i}},
word = "abc"
Output:
{{0,0}}
Explanation:
From (0,0) we can find "abc" in horizontally right direction.

Here are my codes using dfs, I have no idea how my codes can not pass. Anyone can take a look on it? Thanks:)!

```
class Solution:
    def searchWord(self, grid, word):
        res = []
        
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            for j in range(len(grid[0])):
                if self.dfs(i, j, grid, word):
                    res.append([i, j])
                    
        return sorted(res) if res else []
            
            
      
    def dfs(self, row, col, grid, word):
        if not word:
            return True

        if row < 0 or row >= len(grid) or col < 0 or col >= len(grid[0]) or grid[row][col] != word[0] :
            return False

        #backtracking
        directions = [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1)]

        grid[row][col] = '#'
        for dr, dc in directions:
            if self.dfs(row + dr, col + dc, grid, word[1:]):
                return True
        grid[row][col] = word[0]
        return False
```

Wrong or issues in my code

Comment: What are the issues with your code?

Comment: The problem with your algorithm is that you don't maintain the search direction when recursively calling `self.dfs`, meaning you don't guarantee that all of the characters of the word are in the same line.  For example, if you use the Example2 data given on the site `[['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'e', 'b'], ['e', 'b', 'e', 'b']]` and search for the word `'abb'`, your code will return `[[0, 0], [0, 2]]`, while I believe it should return the empty list `[]`

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two problems with your algorithm, which causes to both find some false positives, and to fail to find some answers it should find.

**The first problem with your solution is that it allows "zig-zagging".**

Let's say the test grid is:

```
a b a b
a b e b
e b e b
```

and the search word is 'abb'.  The correct solution should return [], but your solution will return [0,0] and [0,2], using the following routes:

```
[0,0]'a'->[0,1]'b'->[1,1]'b'
[0,2]'a'->[0,3]'b'->[1,3]'b'
```

**The second problem is that you permanently modify the grid**

Your method of modifying a grid value to "#" to prevent backtracking will actually prevent some correct answers from being found, because when the dfs search returns True for a position, you don't revert the value in the grid back to it's original value.
For example:

```
x c x
a b c
x a x
```

We should find `[[1, 0], [2, 1]]`, but your algorithm will only return `[[1,0]]`, as it has permanently modified the grid into

```
x c x
# # #
x a x
```

Here I have updated your solution with the following changes:

1. Added a new parameter to `dfs` named `cur_direction`, which defaults to `None`
2. When `dfs` makes a recursive call, the current direction is passed along
3. If cur_direction is not null, then we don't loop over all directions, we only continue searching in the current direction
4. I removed the code that `set grid[row][col] = '#'` and then restored it, as this solution ensures we can't go back to our previous location while following a word.

```
class Solution:
    def searchWord(self, grid, word):
        res = []
        
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            for j in range(len(grid[0])):
                if self.dfs(i, j, grid, word):
                    res.append([i, j])
                    
        return sorted(res) if res else []
            
      
    def dfs(self, row, col, grid, word, cur_direction=None):
        if not word:
            return True
        
        if row < 0 or row >= len(grid) or col < 0 or col >= len(grid[0]) or grid[row][col] != word[0] :
            return False
        
        # If a direction was passed in, continue searching in that direction.
        if cur_direction:
            return self.dfs(row + cur_direction[0], col + cur_direction[1], grid, word[1:], cur_direction)
            
        #backtracking
        directions = [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1)]

        for dr, dc in directions:
            if self.dfs(row + dr, col + dc, grid, word[1:], (dr, dc)): # Pass along the direction
                return True
        grid[row][col] = word[0]
        return False
```

I have already confirmed this passes all 1120 test cases on GeeksForGeeks.